# Word for laptop and tablet (screen size) but not smartphone or desktop

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm designing a website for three different screen sizes. The laptop and the tablet should be in the same category since the screen sizes make no different nowadays (like: *Surface*, *iPad Pro*).

- Smartphones (`mobile`)
- Laptop & Tablets (`?`)
- Desktop & TV (`widescreen`)

`portable` might be a good idea but a smartphone can also consider as a portable device so it's not gonna work.

`computer` sounds close but it also fits for a `desktop` so it might not be the answer.

Comment: But if your other category is "pocket-sized" then it's obvious that smartphones go in *that* and not *portable*.

Comment: . mobile device?

Comment: The place to ask is on a site like Stack Overflow, not here. But I’d put money on their being no such term. They’ll probably query lumping laptops with tablets rather than desktops, which is more usual. That’s your business, but it’s why I don’t think there’s a word.